# Deserialize JSON in C# using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

I've a class that looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Student {
    [DataMember(Name="name")]
    public string Name {get;set}

    [DataMember(Name="classes")]
    public List<Class> Classes {get; set;}

    public Dictionary<string, object> StudentRawDictionary {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class Class {
    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public Dictionary<string, object> ClassRawDictionary {get; set;}
}
```

This is how I'm deserializing it:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
{
    var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings {UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true};
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Student), settings);
    var student = (Student) serializer.ReadObject(ms);

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), settings);
    var results = (Dictionary<string, object>) serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    student.RawDictionary = results;
    return student;
}
```

My JSON looks something like this:

```
{
    'name' : 'John Doe',
    'email' : 'johndoe@example.com',
    'classes': [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'name': 'History'
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'name': 'Music'
        }
    ]
}
```

Question:
As you can see above, my JSON could contain fields outside that of explicitly listed and annotated `DataMember` (such as email). What I want is to put all the fields, whether they are "listed" or not, in the `xRawDictionary` object. This works fine for `Student` object - I can get `Name` field without a problem. But I ran out of ideas on how to add all the fields to `ClassRawDictionary`.

Is this possible with just .net and no other external dependencies? (I'm writing an open source library so I want to keep dependencies as minimal as possible so I can't use Json.net).